# Implementing a rotateLeft extension for swift sequences

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to implement an extension to sequence that rotates elements from the start of the sequence to the end, eg:

`[1,2,3,4].rotateLeft(2)` gives a sequence like `[3,4,1,2]`.

So far I have:

```swift
extension Sequence {
    func rotateLeft(_ n:Int) -> AnySequence<Iterator.Element> {
        return AnySequence([self.dropFirst(n), self.prefix(n)].joined())
    }
}
```

But this has a typing issue:

> line:3:column:64:(`.joined`): Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I haven't had much luck googling for answers - most answers for type issues are specific to the types involved, and rotateLeft examples are all array-based, not sequence based.

Extracting the sequences to be joined and typing them like so:

```swift
let sequencesToJoin: [AnySequence<Iterator.Element>] = [self.dropFirst(n), self.prefix(n)]
```

Gives the errors:

> Cannot convert value of type '`DropFirstSequence<Self>`' to expected element type '`AnySequence<Self.Element>`'
>
> Cannot convert value of type '`PrefixSequence<Self>`' to expected element type '`AnySequence<Self.Element>`'

I'd like to understand what is going on with the generics. It looks like the sequences returned from `dropFirst` and `prefix`  are sequences with the element type being a sequence (something like `DropFirstSequence<Sequence>`), which seems odd, and possibly the problem. I would expect those methods to return something like `DropFirstSequence<Element>`...

FYI I'm using Xcode `11.3 (11C29)` and Swift 5, with an iOS target.

Comment: Which line or chunk of code specifically is giving you that error?

Comment: The call/reference to `joined` is generating the error (column 64). I suspect since `joined` is overloaded, it needs to know that its `self` is a sequence of sequences, so that it can join them.

Comment: It should be easy enough to open a playground and try to compile this.

Comment: This is a good attempt. The most generic I've been able to do is `Collection where SubSequence: RangeReplaceableCollection`, which gives access to `+`. Good luck! https://github.com/Catterwaul/HemiprocneMystacea/blob/develop/Sources/HM/Swift/extension/Collection/Collection.swift

Comment: Note that iterating over a Sequence multiple times (here: with prefix(n) and dropFirst(n)) is not guaranteed to work. You should implement this on a Collection (which can be enumerated multiple times non-destructively).

Comment: @MartinR I was aware of that, but my tests seem to work for collections, even when implemented on sequences. My thought was that `dropFirst` and `prefix` must copy the sequence? Is that not the case, and it only works on accident?

Comment: It works on collections, but may fail on a sequence which is not a collection. (And if you implement it as `extension Collection` then the compiler error goes away :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by explictly typing intermediary steps:

```
extension Sequence {
  func rotateLeft(_ n:Int) -> AnySequence<Iterator.Element> {
    let s1 = AnySequence<Iterator.Element>(self.dropFirst(n))
    let s2 = AnySequence<Iterator.Element>(self.prefix(n))
    return AnySequence<Iterator.Element>([s1, s2].joined())
  }
}
```

but I have to admit I can't really answer the "why" question.

Comment: I think the `some` keyword would be better than returning a new `AnySequence`, no?

Comment: Returning `some Sequence` as the type removes the `Element` information, evidently. Then the caller doesn't have that type information, so the compiler gives the ambiguous type error at the call site, such as the for loop.

Comment: I think the "why" is that you have to explicitly coerce the sequences to `AnySequence` so that they are compatible to be joined... Best guess anyway. The compiler can't or won't do the implicit conversion. But evidently, the generic type of `AnySequence` is not needed in the coercion call.

Comment: @Jessy I really would like to use `some` if I could, though. It seems like I should be able to, without dropping the associated type information...